How to Hide API Version Tags (v1, v2) in Swagger UI?
I am working on a Golang project where I'm using go-swagger to generate the OpenAPI spec file from code comments, and I'm rendering the Swagger UI using a static HTML template from swagger-ui.
I've implemented API versioning by adding version tags (e.g., v1, v2) in the code comments, which are reflected in the generated spec file. Now, the operations are grouped correctly by version in the UI.
However, I don't want to display the version tags (like v1, v2) in the UI itself when rendering these version-wise operations.Is there a way to hide or exclude these version tags from being displayed in the Swagger UI, while still keeping the versioned APIs?
What I’ve Tried:

Adding tags in the code comments to group API operations by version.
Customizing the Swagger UI, but I haven't found a way to hide specific tags (like v1, v2) without affecting the API grouping.

I want the UI to show versioned operations but without explicitly displaying the version tags (e.g., v1, v2) in the tag list.
